# Read determined part of one text file ignoring comments - Language C

Tags: c, file, pointers, text, int

Imagine I have one text file with this content:

```
hi world
#just random text
123 010 780
```

And i want to do a function able to return, based on position in the file, just 123 as an int,
another one to just get 780.
All this ignoring comments "#asdjhajsdkn".

Comment: ok .. what have you tried so far?

Comment: just compare the first symbol in the line with the indicator of comment

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading a line using [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), strip leading (and possibly trailing) whitespace. If the first character then is a `'#'` then continue to read the next line. If the first character is a digit (use e.g. [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit)) then use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to convert to a number, and use the second parameter to know where the next number on the line is, so you should call `strtol` in a loop.

Comment: im with something like this:
  
int char;

  char = getc(filename);
  if (char == '#') {
    do {
      char = getc(filename);
    } while (char != '\n' && char != EOF);
  }
  return char;


my problem is, i want to, probably using a pointer, indicate where i want to start read

Comment: @user2971826 With a text file you can't really have fixed positions, as the text may vary.

Comment: Yes i do, im trying make this function to read more files with the same struct, i mean, anything then comments then some int's